# Post image to Instagram from a Javascript using Instagram API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Instagram Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Content Publishing:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

My code `Javascript` in `Google App Script`:

```
function InstagramPost() {

  const id = '123456789';
  const image = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg';
  const text = 'Hello%20World';
  const access_token = 'TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST';
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/' + id + '/media?image_url=' + image + '&caption=' + text + '&access_token=' + access_token;

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container);
  const creation = response.getContentText();

  Logger.log(creation);
}
```

The return in my Logger of my container to Post via Instagram API request comes as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "11111111111111111"
    },
    {
      "id": "22222222222222222"
    },
    {
      "id": "33333333333333333"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QWOURQWNGEWRONHWENYWPETGNWQPGNPGNWEPGNWEPGNWEPNGWPENGPWEG",
      "after": "WIWEPGNEPBNWE´GNÉ´BNWE´BNWÉBWNEB´WENBNWEBWEBEWBWE"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/11111111111111111/media?access_token=PQWNFWPQINPWNBQPWNBQPWNBPQWNVQWPNVPQWVNPQWPVNQPWNVQPWVNQPWNVPQWNVQPWNVQPWVNQASASLGÇAJKSGLJAAÇSNAÇKNSVÇLKNASBÇANSBÇAS"
  }
}
```

To make the final call for post image it is necessary to use an `creation_id=`:

```
const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/' + id + '/media_publish?creation_id=' + creation + '&access_token=' + access_token;
UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram);
```

If the return from the container is several `id` in sequence, how do I know which one to define for the call?

Note: I can't loop to try every id because Instagram has a daily limit of 25 calls and posts, so if I did that I would end up with my calls just trying to post a single image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct way to publish images:

```
  var formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media';

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var formDataPublish = {
      'creation_id': creationId,
      'access_token': access_token
  };
  var optionsPublish = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formDataPublish
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media_publish';
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram, optionsPublish);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I am trying to run this program but I have not been able to find a correct way to get `access token` and `instagram_business_account` information, kindly can you please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: @Roomi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038880/generate-non-expiring-token-for-facebook-graph-api-to-publish-on-instagram-busin/73039928#73039928

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

First, we create IG Container by hitting the endpoint.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{ig-user-id}/media?image_url={image-url}&caption={caption}&access_token={access-token}
```

Once you have the IG container ID then we again make a POST request to post the Image.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{ig-user-id}/media_publish?creation_id={creation-id}&access_token={access-token}
```

*I think you have to include the version in **container** and **sendinstagram** which is v11.0 (latest as if now).*

Comment: Hi @sakigo Unfortunately when I do this path, it actually delivers the Media Objects values, not the ```creation_id```. Does not solve the problem of publishing itself

Comment: Hi @BrondbyIF Once you make the POST request for getting the IG Container ID then it returns an Object (eg: { "id": "33333333333333333"}) which is the **creation_id**.  We make use of this id value in the next POST request. If you are getting different values in the object then please let me know that object fields.

Comment: According to your indications, the result obtained is not the simple publication ID, it returns the topic ```6. Get the Instagram Business Account's Media Objects``` in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started, there are several ids of publications and other records, but not the id for the new publication, unfortunately

Comment: Friend, I updated the question for better viewing!

Comment: According to [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) it is making a GET request. Getting those values is kind of uncertain. I would suggest you check the URL again and use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  to get the **creation_id**.