# Post to Instagram via API

Tags: google-apps-script, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I've been trying to setup a small app using Google Apps Script that just posts to Instagram. I got the bulk of the code I'm using from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930697/post-image-to-instagram-from-a-javascript-using-instagram-api).

```
 function postToIG() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('IG Post');
  var image = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var text = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var access_token = "TOKEN";
  var formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/ID/media';

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var formDataPublish = {
      'creation_id': creationId,
      'access_token': access_token
  };
  var optionsPublish = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formDataPublish,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/ID/media_publish';
  
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram, optionsPublish);
  console.log(response2.getContentText());
}
```

I just keep getting the same error message for both requests in the code

> {"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID
> 'ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
> permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
> API documentation at
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"AtTVaV-ODec9Iuagp4efYuX"}}

I'm not sure how exactly to get the Instagram user ID that would go in for the ID value in the code. I've tried several different methods and gotten different IDs and I get the same error for all of them.

My account is a business account and linked to a Facebook page. Furthermore, I got the access token being used from the Graph API Explorer on the Facebook developers site. I added all of the permissions listed for the [media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#creating) and [media_publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media_publish#creating) endpoints. Additionally, the Instagram Graph API product is added to the app I've created for this on the Facebook developers page.

**EDIT:**

Got what I think is the correct ID using the Graph API Explorer and accessing the endpoint "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me/accounts" however even using this new ID value I am still getting the same error message as shown above

**UPDATE**

I was able to figure this out. I did have the correct ID value however it turns out there is also an Instagram Business Account ID that can be retrieved using the Graph API Explorer. Once I started using this ID, it ran just fine

Comment: _"I'm not sure how exactly to get the Instagram user ID"_ - FB user needs to log in, then you need to get their FB page that is connected to the IG account, and get the IG account ID from that page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Comment: It seems that in your script, there are 2 requests. About `I just keep getting the same error message`, where the line does the error occurs at?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm getting the same error message for both requests

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I'm getting the same error message for both requests`, in your script, both 2 requests return the same error message of `{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'ID' does not exist`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Taniake that is correct